# Can I use OR instruction between A and B registers in HC12 (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, boolean, concatenation

I would just like to give me guidance on how to do to make a program that takes two 8 data bits stored in memory, then take the most significant part of one them and the least significant of the other and save as a result.

Example: 
Data 1: 19 
Data 2: 3A 
Result: 1A

For the moment I've done this.

-Step 1. registers A and B are used to store data of 8 bits.

-Step 2. We use the instruction ANDA with the first 8-bit value in the register
A.

-Step 3. We use the ANDB instruction with the second 8-bit value in the register B.

But I don't know how to use OR to concatenate A or B.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: and what did you find in the instruction set?   From elementary school what do you get when you add anything with zero?  the instruction set will show you what OR options you have and what ADD options you have...

Comment: *concatenate* A and B?  If you really mean that, the D register (A and B together) is exactly that 16 bit concatenation; you don't need to do any work.  If you mean "OR" A and B, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If in step 2, you and A with a mask to extract the MSB, and in step 3 you and B with a mask for the LSB, then you can "OR"   A and B by using the "ABA" instruction.

While ABA is technically an ADD,  when you "ADD" any bit X to a zero bit, you get X.   Since the corresponding bits in A and B are zeroed, the ABA acts effectively as an OR.

Alternatively, you can store the B register into a page zero cell, and OR that cell into the A register.    Clumsy but clear.  If you aren't conscious about code space or time, you might choose this solution for clarity; the ABA solution isn't obvious unless you think about it.  (Most people doing serious coding for a machine architecture actually know these tricks by heart so it might not matter).